# Going "into", "in", or "to" the sea?

Tags: prepositions

- > He went **into** sea alone.
- > He went **in** sea alone.
- > He went **to** sea alone.

What is the difference in all these sentences?  Are they grammatically correct?

As per my knowledge **into** means an entry so he is entering the sea. Secondly **in** refers to something located inside or within so I believe going in the sea is wrong. And the last one going **to** sea is correct.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to write "*the* sea". Also, this is not an issue of grammar but meaning.

More context is necessary to choose, but in general:

> He went **to** the sea alone.

This means you went to the area near the sea. If I went to a coastal area, I could say this. But it does not really mean in/on the water.

> He went **into** the sea alone.

This means he went from being "out of the water" to "in the water".

> He went **in** the sea alone.

Same as "into" when using *went*, since motion is indicated.

Generally I would use *on the sea* when you are traveling in a boat.